# PBR Material Mix Multiplied Colors

Tags: node-editor

This PBR Material is multiplying Albedo + AO. I want to keep that but be able to change the Base color. Added a Mix node, but not sure if this is the best way to do this. It kida works. Also in the Mix node does it matter which color is selected first, Color 1, or Color2?
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to keep the texture granularity and details, you can try switching the operation from Mix to Color for instance. You'll have to swap both inputs because the base color is always the top one

Comment: Worked great Thank you!

Comment: At closer inspection this is not working. The color specs from the albedo are getting covered by the Mix color. how to tint the Base color but preserve the Albedo color details?

Comment: It's not clear from the picture you added : If you set the factor to 0 the node effectively doesn't do anything if the operation is set to Color.